# How do I scrap div in nav with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap this site https://www.fxhash.xyz/marketplace/generative/15063 with Selenium and i want all the activity on the activity onglet.
But first i can't click on the acticity buttoun to have the right page.

Can someone help me ??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNDyI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQZD8.png)

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(),"activity")]').click()

activities = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//article[@class="Action_container__uURkZ Action_is_link__7x4O4"]')
```